# apply dropdown list if a specific cell is full on google sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

as my programing skills isn't the best I'm asking you guys here for help with my issue that I have, I want a dropdown list to appear if a specific cell is not empty, for example if A3 is not empty a dropdown list needs to appear in E3 but if A3 is empty nothing E3 needs to be empty.
for now the only thing I find is to create the dropdown list that it's working for me good, but for the rest I couldn't fin something helpful
this is all the code that I could make but only the function MyFunction that it's working good for me and creating the dropdown list

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var variable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("variable");
var option = variable.getRange(1,1,variable.getLastRow(),1);

function myFunction() {
  var list =["a","b","c","d"];
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  var cell = ws.getRange("D2");
  applyValidation(list,cell);
}


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCEll = e.range;
  var val = activeCEll.getValue();
  var r = activeCEll.getRow();
  var c = activeCEll.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCEll.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName =="Sheet2" && c===1 && r > 1){
    ws.getRange(r,2).setValue(myFunction);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should this apply to all cells in column A? Should the dropdown data validation be deleted from the cell in column E or can it remain, simply blank?  I don't see where you use the `rule` and what `applyValidation()` does.  You keep mentioning A and E but don't reference these column in your `onEdit()`.

Comment: the A and E are just examples, and my code as i said my function it's what i'm sure of it working good but the rest is just a try from me

Comment: I guess I have trouble understanding the question.  If you simply applied Data Validation from the menu to column E, the cells of column E would be blank but with the drop down arrow on the right.  If you place a value in A that doesn't change the value or appearance of E. You still have to navigate to E and select a value from the dropdown.  So the need for a script to do this escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if(sh.getName() =="Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value === ''){
    const list =["a","b","c","d"];
    const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
    e.range.offset(0,5).setDataValidation(rule);//e
  }
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if(sh.getName() =="Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value !== ''){
    e.range.offset(0,5).clearDataValidations();//e
  }
}
```